# After reboot prompted for a password and logged to a different user

Tags: catalina, security, password, privacy, login-screen

something strange happened on my mac and it looks like a serious security/privacy bug. We have two accounts with different passwords (lets call it: primary/secondary) on my Macbook Air 2018 with macOS Catalina. The battery died while the secondary user was logged in. I connected the charger and turned it on. The login screen showed up, so I selected the primary user and typed the password. Now the weird stuff happens - I was logged in as the secondary user and I was able to do anything on the secondary's user screen - view mail, etc. When I logged out the screen started to switch me between two accounts and asking for a password. Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Isn't this the normal Fast User switching?

Comment: no, I wasn't prompted for the secondary user password. The secondary user also has different touch id setup